# Excel VBA: Cut a row from one sheet onto another and affix date to the end

Tags: vba, excel

I'm trying to cut the row I type Complete next to and move it to a completed sheet. I'm lost because I don't know how to add the date to the end of it. Ideally, I would type 'Complete' in the D column and the A,B, and C cells in that row would be cut over to the next line down on Sheet 2 (Completed Tasks). Also, on Sheet 2 in column E, the current date would be added.

Here is the code I have so far. I don't have a clue how to get the date to affix.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
Dim C As Range
If Intersect(Target, Me.Range("D:D")) Is Nothing Then Exit Sub
For Each C In Intersect(Target, Me.Range("D:D")).Cells
If C.Text = "Complete" Then
C.EntireRow.Copy Worksheets("Completed Tasks").Cells(Rows.Count,"C").End(xlUp).Offset(1).EntireRow
  C.Clear
  C.Offset(0, -2).Clear
 End If
 Next
End Sub
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

How about this? Also, are you trying to clear the entire C row? It looks like you are only clearing two C row cells (Column D and Column B), but I could be wrong. Also, would you like to delete the entire row on the first sheet so the unfinished tasks move up into the blank spaces?

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
Dim C As Range

If Intersect(Target, Me.Range("D:D")) Is Nothing Then Exit Sub

For Each C In Intersect(Target, Me.Range("D:D")).Cells
    If C.Text = "Complete" Then
        C.Offset(0,1).Value = Now 'Adds the date to Column E
        C.Offset(0,1).NumberFormat = ("mm/dd/yyyy") 'Formats the "Now" in a recognizable date way, I assume you are in the US
        C.EntireRow.Copy Worksheets("Completed Tasks").Cells(Rows.Count,"C").End(xlUp).Offset(1).EntireRow
        C.Clear 'Clears Column D?
        C.Offset(0, -2).Clear 'Clears Column B? What about A and C?
    End If
Next C

End Sub
```

Comment: Wow! That works exactly how I needed it to work. Thank you thank you!

Comment: @MatthewDiluzio You're welcome! Thank you for putting effort into your question!